# Debugging an Azure web role started with csrun.exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, integration-testing, azure-web-roles

I have a Visual Studio solution that has a cloud project with one web role (containing an ASP.NET MVC Web API). If I hit F5, the Azure emulator is started and I can debug the web role fine.

I also have a test project that contains integration tests, to test the web api end to end. In the AssemblyInitialize operation, I use csrun.exe to deploy and start the Azure emulator like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe"
  ..\..\..\..\Sources\Cfg.Mgp.Infrastructure.Cloud\csx\Debug
  ..\..\..\..\Sources\Cfg.Mgp.Infrastructure.Cloud\bin\Debug\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
  /useiisexpress
```

So if I start the tests, the Azure emulator is ready and tests are executed fine.
This all works.

However, if I want to debug this starting from my integration tests, the breakpoints in the Web API are not hit (but it is executed fine). I tried attaching the debugger to IISExpress, WaHostBootstrapper and other processes, but nothing works.

Does anyone have any idea how to debug a web role if the Azure emulator is started with csrun.exe?

(Remark: if I hit F5, a browser is launched; and if I then run the integration tests the breakpoints in the web role are hit fine.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing today - without the `/useiisexpress` flag. What happened is I noticed on local IIS that a website was made from the compute emulator. I restarted Rider as Administrator, placed a testing breakpoint, attached to w3wp.exe and it worked.