# Database Project in Visual Studio hangs on “Analyzing Database Schema…

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, database-schema

I am using VS2012 Ultimate and have created a ".sqlproj"

I don't know what is making the VS take so time to load the projects of the solution.

I have also tried Repairing as well as re-installing my VS2012 Ult but still the same.

VS hangs with the status at bottom:
**"Analyzing Database Schema. Your database projects will be ready after 1561 operations are completed."**

Comment: I'd start by making sure you have the newest version of SSDT (June 2013) installed, and then also make sure you have the DACFx (June 2013) installed in both 32/64-bit versions.

Comment: hey Kevin,
    can u just forward me the links to download the newest version of SSDT (June'13) & DACFx(JUn'13).

Comment: Sure, here's the SSDT blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/06/24/announcing-sql-server-data-tools-june-2013.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ssdtblog+%28SQL+Server+Developer+Tools+Team+Blog%29 and here's the DACfx one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/06/25/sql-server-data-tier-application-framework-june-2013-available.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ssdtblog+%28SQL+Server+Developer+Tools+Team+Blog%29

Comment: hey i found that these plugins were installed already in my system.

Comment: but then too, i formatted my system and again installed the same VS 2012 Ultimate & Azure April 2013 release SDK.

And now, i cannot run any of the cloud projects.  I get the following error: "There was an error attaching the debugger to the role instance" 

kindly refer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748917/there-was-an-error-attaching-the-debugger-to-the-role-instance-while-loading-any

Comment: See, if this thread is helpful to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409083/debugging-azure-error-attaching-the-debugger-to-the-iis-worker-proccess

Comment: Do you have the possibilty to upgrade to Visual Studio 2013 ?