# Windows Azure project not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am using Visual Studio 2012 using C#.

I am getting error while opening the project at my PC, this project is working fine on another system.

[image: I am getting this error]

Very frequently I am also getting this error too.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have the [latest Azure SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/?sdk=net) and disable all your plugins

Answer (score 0):

how many instances are you trying to run? small hint here, try to run the emulator before you run the solution, it helps sometimes. Second try it with the express emulator feature (new since sdk 2.1)

Comment: thanks @techmike2kx for this solution I will try and let you know, 
I can see program installed as "Windows Azure Emulator - v2.1" in installed programs list in Control Panel. 
Now would I be able to run express emulator as you mentioned if yes then how ?
....
what type of instance you are pointing to?

Comment: I tried as you said, but I am unable to use express mode when project starts running. Now msot of the time I am getting the same error like in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409083/debugging-azure-error-attaching-the-debugger-to-the-iis-worker-proccess . But unable to proceed with the answers as I have no idea how to proceed.